# Copy constructor usage with pointer

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have a question about the usage of copy constructors. I know that there are many other answered questions and a huge variety of tutorials but I could not completely solve my problem.

I have a class `A` which implements a copy constructor:

```
A::A(const A& a) { ....... }
```

Now in another class `B`, I have a private attribute:

```
A myA;
```

During execution, a method of `B` gets called with a pointer to an `A` object, lets call it `anAPointer`. I now want to copy the element pointed by `anAPointer` into `B::myA`. If the element behind the pointer later changes, I don't want these changes to affect the `myA` attribute.

I used `this->myA = A(*anAPointer);` yet. Does this have the effect I want it to have?

And do I have to call `delete myA` in `B`'s destructor?

Comment: There is no need to create a temporary variable, just use: `this->myA = *anAPointer;`

Comment: *And do I have to call delete myA in B's destructor?* --  No one knows what the context is of how your objects are being used.  So unless you post a [mcve], no one could give you a definite answer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `myA` is clearly stated as a non pointer attribute in the OP, so it can be answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
A(*anAPointer)
```

is calling `A`'s copy constructor so `this->myA` will be an instance of `A` unrelated to the value pointed by `anAPointer`. Changes to the first won't be propagated to the other and vice versa (unless your class `A` handles shared resources, but that's not pointed in your question).

`myA` is not a pointer, so you don't have to call `delete` in `B`'s destructor.

Note that if you're implementing copy constructor in `A`, you should consider [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) and maybe [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I did everything correct?

Comment: Looks like you did to me from your question. Make some tests to be sure ;)

Comment: Depending of what `A` actually does, also consider rule of 3/5/0 and copy and swap idiom in your design. See my edited answer with the links